# How To Correctly Specify Image path from a folder (ImageIcon)

Tags: java, swing, embedded-resource, imageicon

I was following a reference and some tutorial on setting the path of an image for a JLabel but can't get the path correctly.

I have

```
String pathToUserPictureImage = "resources/Assets/studentPhoto.png";
    ImageIcon userPicture = new ImageIcon(getClass().getClassLoader().getResource(pathToUserPictureImage));
        JLabel userPictureImagePlaceHolder = new JLabel(userPicture, HEIGHT);
```

And my folders in the project are:

[image]

When I run it, it would return an error message about a Null Pointer which I suspect to be a problem with the path supplied.

I would appreciate any suggestion and correction to my code. I recently just switched from dragging and dropping components to writing code by hand.

Comment: `/Assets/studentPhoto.png` - I can't see any `resources` directory in your source tree

Comment: @MadProgrammer, thanks. My bad, I didn't have to put the "Resources" It worked when I put String pathToUserPictureImage = "Assets/studentPhoto.png"; Didn't have to add an src folder from projects. I guess I'm tired. But I appreciate the help. Thanks.

Comment: More examples [here](http://stackoverflow.com/tags/embedded-resource/info) in the [tag:embedded-resource] tag.